# Error while retrieving information from server [DF-AA-20]

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

Receiving error while doing in-app purchase in my app in android.
Error while retrieving information from server [DF-AA-20]

Comment: Welcome!  You'll need to share a lot more information.  Have you tried [Googling your issue](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Receiving+error+while+doing+in-app+purchase+in+my+app+in+android.+Error+while+retrieving+information+from+server+[DF-AA-20])?  Please check out [mcve] as well as the [tour] and [ask] and then [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: i have googled the same issue but didn't find any solution.

Comment: i have integrated in-app purchase in my app, but when i am trying to click on the button to purchase it shows me the error on google-play window.

Comment: There are hundreds of possible solutions in the search results; which ones have you tried, and what was the results.  Did you see the links, like [mcve]?

Comment: @S.Shaikh This simply means your app is not published yet in play store.

Comment: My problem was that I had not published my APK properly in Alpha. Once it turned to "Published" the error went away. Now I get another erro "The item you requested is not available for purchase." Not sure why though as it's an active managed item with the correct name...

Answer (score 17):

Make sure you have followed the below steps:

1. Login to the Play Console with your developer account.
2. Copy the application's public key (a base-64 string). You can find this in the "Services & APIs" section under "Development tools" and replace in your code.
3. Make signed apk and upload (not publish) in ALPHA, and add your test account (the one you will use to test purchases) to the "testers" section of your app. Your test account CANNOT BE THE SAME AS THE PUBLISHER ACCOUNT.
4. Click Settings > Account details, then in the License Testing section, add the Google email addresses for your tester accounts.
5. Under In-app Products, create your product and make active.
6. Use your product id in code and make a signed build and Publish in the Alpha channel wait until the status change to "Published".
7. Test the app in tester account enabled device.

Comment: this worked, thank you!

Comment: I followed the Google play Billing docs, i didn't see any mention of the app public key?

Comment: @PavelPoley, Console has been updated so now you can find this under "Development tools"

Comment: and they mentioned in doc of sample code also.

Comment: You do not need the public key

Answer (score 11):

ProductID is invalid! maybe have space char or other chars!

Comment: Extra space is the culprit for me

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you are using the right ProductID and check if you have that ProductID set to "active" in "In-app products" in your Google Play Console.

You can also add a new ProductID and try if you get the same error.

Comment: Hey, i have used right ProductID and it is activated on google play console.

Comment: Hello, any update for the solution, its day 3 i am facing this issue. Please help....

Comment: @S.Shaikh Even i am facing same issue from last 2 days....

Comment: I am too facing this issue. Can someone please help?

Comment: Chief! The product was not active for me... I had to activate it, was my bad. Thank you dude.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Issue, but as @Parodius says you need to change your product's SKU,  I solved using:

```
 Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getActivity().getPackageName(),
                                        "remover_publicidad", "inapp", "DFOSYwWKWv");
```

Where "remover_publicidad" is my SKU. Also, If you wanna see the dialog with the button to proceed the purchase you must use an Android Device with a different Google Account than your developer account email.