# What does 'error while retrieving information from server [DF - AA - 33] mean and how do I solve this error? Google play store?

Tags: flutter, google-play

I have a flutter test app in the google playstore. It was working for the past weeks. Now one of my friends was installing this app and he received this error:

```
error while retrieving information from server [DF - AA - 33]
```

I'm not quiet sure what the error means. Can you explain it please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768655/error-while-retrieving-information-from-server-df-aa-20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of the devices were facing this error on 9th April 2019 (today) I received following error which seems relatable.

Well you can search your app again and you should not face the same error now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a temporary internal error from the Play Store. If it persists then you should contact Play console developer support via the help menu on the Play Console. This is behind the "?" icon. It means something is wrong with Play, not with your app, and it is helpful to report it.